# Eliminar Usuario de Tabla AspNetUsers MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Como puedo eliminar usuarios que he creado en la tabla AspNetUsers, trabajo bajo MVC5.

Mi código es el siguiente,

AccountController.cs:

```
 //INDEX LIST USERS ADM
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            List<AspNetUserstb> users = (from o in userContext.Users
                                         join p in userContext.Roles on o.Roles.Select(t => t.RoleId).FirstOrDefault() equals p.Id
                                         select new AspNetUserstb
                                         {
                                             Id = o.Id,
                                             Email = o.Email,
                                             Rol = p.Name
                                         }).ToList();

            return View(users);
        }
```

Mi vista.

Index.cshtml:

```
<h2>Usuarios SI</h2>

<p>
    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register")'" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Usuario</button>
</p>
<div class="stylepagination">
    <table id="usersadm" class="table nowrap table-bordered table-hover display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rol)
                </th>
                <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Administrar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rol)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                            <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Resetpw", "Account", new { id = item.Id })'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Reset Password</button>
                            <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Deluser", "Account", new { id = item.Id })'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

y por ultimo mi modelo.

AccountViewModels.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SI_OldMutual.Models
{
    public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalLoginListViewModel
    {
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class SendCodeViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
        public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerifyCodeViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "¿Recordar este explorador?")]
        public bool RememberBrowser { get; set; }

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForgotViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "¿Recordar cuenta?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El número de caracteres de {0} debe ser al menos {2}.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar contraseña")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "La contraseña y la contraseña de confirmación no coinciden.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Required]
        public string rol { get; set; }

    }

    public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El número de caracteres de {0} debe ser al menos {2}.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar contraseña")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "La contraseña y la contraseña de confirmación no coinciden.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class AspNetUserstb
    {
        [Display(Name = "Id")]
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rol")]
        public virtual string Rol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lo único que necesito es eliminar el usuario que yo seleccione en la tabla que tengo hecha actualmente, dicha tabla tiene el botón eliminar y tal botón lleva el id del usuario que quiero eliminar de la tabla AspNetUsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes crear la acción para eliminar el usuario recibiendo el `Id` del usuario que deseas eliminar, ese `Id` actualmente ya lo envías en el `View`:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Deluser", "Account", new { id = item.Id })'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
```

Acción del Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Deluser(string id)
{
   using (var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
   {
        var objUser = (from p in userContext.Users
                                where p.Id == id
                                select p).FirstOrDefault();

        userContext.Users.Remove(objUser);

        userContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Account");   
   }
}
```

Básicamente, el funcionamiento es, buscar al usuario, realizar el `delete` y confirmar los cambios para que se actualice la base de datos, finalmente, solo realizar el *redirect*  al `Index` para que la página se refresque.

Comment: El id es un string, solo cambio el Deluser(int id) por Deluser(string id) ?

Comment: @ByGroxD Listo :) gracias por la observación

Comment: Che Flxtr no me funciono, dice no tiene una definicion para AspNetUsers

Comment: @Xique jaja ntp hombre, si tienes una respuesta diferente pero que también pueda solucionar el problema del OP ponla, igual y también le puede ayudar

Comment: @ByGroxD ¿en qué línea te sale eso?

Comment: AspNetUserstb objUser = from p in userContext.AspNetUsers

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58414/discussion-between-bygroxd-and-flxtr).